# how can we avoid if else while creating keys in object?

Tags: javascript

Suppose i have an object `obj={}` and another object `x={a:1 , b: 2}`, i want to create a key on this only when required without using if/else block.

for example

```
    if ( x.a)
     obj.a = 1

    if ( x.b)
     obj.a = 1

    ...
```

Approach which i used was

- using pipe operator ||

> obj.a = x.a || null;

in this case `obj.a = 1`

but if i use (when p1 property does not exist in object x)

```
obj.p1 = x.p1 || null
```

`obj.c = null` will be created.in this case c is unnecessarily created

is there any solution to avoid if/else and not create unnecessary keys too .

Comment: What do you aim to accomplish by avoiding `if` statements?

Comment: your code is not faster without the `if` (in case you are worried about performance). It is also less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there any solution to avoid if/else and not create unnecessary keys too .

Since an assignment is an expression, it's technically possible to "abuse" the boolean AND operator for its side effect:

```
(x.a || x.b) && (obj.a = 1);
```

But you probably shouldn't do that because it makes your code harder to understand. An `if` statement is explicit and clear.

If you actually want to *copy* properties from one object to the other, see [Christopher Harris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46699765/218196).

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ES6, You might benefit from `Object.assign`.

```
var o1 = { a: 5 };
var o2 = { a: 13, b: 12 };
var o3 = { c: 7 };
var o = Object.assign(o1, o2, o3); // { a: 13, b: 12, c: 7 }
```

A polyfill can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).